# Spring boot REST Paths like profile and users

Tags: spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application with below starters 
[image]
I need to know why we have these REST end points

```
{
_links: {
users: {
href: "http://localhost:8080/users"
},
profile: { 
href: "http://localhost:8080/profile"
}
}
}
```

Comment: Do you have entity users and profile?

Comment: i have entity user but not profile or users

Comment: i got somthing here https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/14/spring-data-rest-now-comes-with-alps-metadata

Comment: You have REST Repositories which add rest endpoints to your entitites. So you probably have UserRepository.findAll and this repository is exposed as {url}/users. Similar situation shoudl be with profile but if you don have repository for it so I don't know why it is exposed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have `Rest Repositories` dependency.

From [Spring Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#metadata.alps),

> Spring Data REST provides an Application-Level Profile Semantics (ALPS) document for every exported
>   repository. It contains information about both the RESTful transitions
>   and the attributes of each repository.
>
> At the root of a Spring Data REST app is a profile link. Assuming you
>   had an app with both persons and related addresses, the root document
>   would be as follows:

```
{   
   "_links" : {
     "persons" : {
     "href" : "http://localhost:8080/persons"
    },
     "addresses" : {
     "href" : "http://localhost:8080/addresses"
    },
     "profile" : {
     "href" : "http://localhost:8080/profile" 
    }   
  } 
}
```

And `/users` is there because you might have it as an endpoint or as `@marok` has mentioned in comments it is because `UserRepository` is exposed that way.

Hope it helps !

Comment: Is there a way we can disable this?